# Linux - Limit user to one application in ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, shell, login

This is something that I looked into a while back and found some useful info for... but now that I actually need to do it, of course I can't find that guide I saw anymore.

Anyways, here's the situation. I have a program that runs using an ncurses menu through SSH. I want users to be able to login to that program via SSH, but only to that program.

What do I have to do so that this scenario is possible?

- User opens Putty
- User signs into the Linux server with their username and password
- When logging in, they go straight to that program
- In the even of a program close, crash, cancellation, etc... the user is forcefully loged off of the system.

My goal is to limit them from seeing a command line at all, and to be restricted to just that program. Is this possible? How do I/would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 6):

This is also called a captive login.

Append to the user's ~/.profile an execution of the program and an exit.

```
exec /usr/local/bin/program
exit
```

Clever users know they can supply a command in their ssh client that isn't the shell you expect. Prevent that with ForceCommand in your sshd config:

> ## [ForceCommand](http://man.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5?query=sshd_config#ForceCommand)
>
> Forces the execution of the command specified by ForceCommand,
>   ignoring any command supplied by the client and ~/.ssh/rc if present.
>   The command is invoked by using the user's login shell with the -c
>   option. This applies to shell, command, or subsystem execution. It is
>   most useful inside a Match block.

```
Match Group programusers
    ForceCommand /usr/local/bin/program
```

Comment: A better way is to use `command=` in the `authorized_keys` so that you tie a specific command to a specific key. Very useful for backups.

Comment: A force command may be either in the sshd configuration or in the user's authorized_keys.  ForceCommand also works when the user is using non-key (password) auth. And the administrator puts it in one place, versus across all user's key files.

Comment: Typically, for backups, the client is some automated process so obviously using a key, not a password. And typically the user then is root, not any other user.